# Eclipse Tomcat: requires the ARP/native library which is not available

Tags: java, tomcat

I downloaded the 32 bit `tcnative-1.dll` file and follow this guide `https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/apr.html`. I put the `tcnative-1.dll` file in this location `C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.38\bin`. When I start tomcat in eclipse, below error is showed. I am not sure what I missed or what I did wrong

For your information, I am using windows OS, 64 bit system, a 32bit Java version and a 32 bit `tcnative-1.dll` file.

Tomcat Error

[image: Tomcat Error]

Server.xml

[image]

Tomcat Folder

[image]